# Big Space below ToolBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I try to use my own Toolbars in two Activities that have the `ConstraintLayout`.
In one Activity, I placed a button below the toolbar, what looks fine:
[image: image showing the good activity]

However, in the other Activity, I placed a `ListView` below the toolbar and suddenly there is a big gap between the Toolbar and the ListView:
[image: image showing the bad activity]

I should note that this does not appear in the preview in `AndroidStudio`.
The layout of the Activities is exactly the same and in the `Manifest`, I set the application theme to `NoActionBar`.

I am happy about any kind of help :)

Here is some of the code of the "bad" Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.nutritionanalyzer.RecipeOverviewActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/recipe_overview_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/recipeOverviewListView"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recipe_overview_toolbar" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Maybe the line

```
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
```

is guilty? But I have exactly the same line at the "good" Activity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set `android:layout_height="0dp"` in ListView because when you set width and height of a child in constraint layout to something other than zero and anchor edges of the child the view will be centered between anchor points because you have set these attributes (you have anchor view's top and bottom edges):

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recipe_overview_toolbar" />
```

I guess that you also want listView to match parent width if you want this just set `android:layout_width="0dp"` because you have these attributes in listView (you have anchor listView horizontally to parent):

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
```

and remove:

```
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!